# Return Null if no value is retrieved by join

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I wish to write a query to return the a result by joining three tables:

[image]

`ReceiptID` in the Result is picked by `FeeID` 841. If the Client doesn't have a receipt or the clients receipt doesn't have FeeID 841 the result should be `NULL`.

Comment: What have you tried?  You can accomplish this by using what's called an `outer join`...

Comment: Left Join did the trick. I guess i was looking at the duplicates and got confused with the return set. Used Distinct(ClientID) to sort that out. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

Your exepected results do not make any sense, since it excludes receipts that are associated with clients. But his is a simple join...

```
declare @Table1 table (ApplicationID int identity (1,1), ClientID int)

declare @Table2 table (RecieptID int identity(1,1), ClientID int)

declare @Table3 table (ID int identity(1,1), RecepitID int, FeeID int)

insert into @Table1
values
(1), (2), (3)

insert into @Table2
values
(1), (1), (3)

insert into @Table3
values
(1, 841), (2, 840), (3, 220)

select
    t1.ApplicationID
    ,t1.ClientID
    ,t2.RecieptID
    ,t3.FeeID
from
    @Table1 t1
    left join @Table2 t2 on t1.ClientID = t2.ClientID
    left join @Table3 t3 on t3.RecepitID = t2.RecieptID
```

Comment: The intention is to only focus on a particular fee paid by clients. Actually I was making a report to reconcile with those that have applied and paid and those that did not. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: So a where clause should remediate this?